# Error - "Access denied to the path"

Tags: asp.net, windows, security

I have an asp.net application having a class library referenced in the web project i.e.I am calling a class library method with the parameters (file path in the server machine). I tried accessing the path from the class library. I am getting the error saying ""

1. I am using windows server 2003 machine and I have given permissions to ASPNET and tried giving to IUSR_Machine but couldnt find the name.
2. I checked in Google, said like, need to add network services account. How to add this and is there any need to add for running an asp net application in windows server 2003.

please suggest the solution for this.

Thanks in Advance
Rupa

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know you need the "network service" user to have access to the folder your website is.
you can add this user rights same as you would any other user.

Comment: I believe this works. The peer is using ASPNET instead of NetworkService user.

Answer (score 0):

check the user in ApplicationPool, and set is access to the folder/files that you need to access